# Como verificar se uma lista contém 3 números consecutivos

Tags: python, lista

Inserir um vetor com 10 valores inteiros aleatórios.
Em seguida verificar se existe no vetor alguma sequência de 3 números consecutivos.
Dois valores são consecutivos se a diferença for 1 unidade

exemplo:

A = [10, 5, 7, 9, 20, 16, 11, 12, 13, 3]

Neste vetor, existem 3 valores consecutivos que são: 11, 12 e 13

**O que eu consegui até agora foi só isso**

```
C = []

A = [10, 5, 7, 9, 20, 16, 11, 12, 13, 3]

for i in range(len(A) - 1):

    if A[i] == A[i + 1] - 1:

        C.append(A[i])
        C.append(A[i + 1])

print(C)
```

Answer (score 2):

Bom, para cada elemento, você precisa verificar os 2 próximos (ou seja, para cada posição `i`, você precisa verificar as posições `i + 1` e `i + 2`). Então você deve iterar até `len - 2` em vez de `len - 1`:

```
numeros = [10, 5, 7, 9, 20, 16, 11, 12, 13, 3]
for i in range(len(numeros) - 2):
    if numeros[i] + 1 == numeros[i + 1] == numeros[i + 2] - 1:
        print(f'Tem 3 números consecutivos: {numeros[i]}, {numeros[i + 1]}, {numeros[i + 2]}')
        break
else:
    print('não tem 3 números consecutivos')
```

No `for`, basta ver se o elemento da posição `i` somado com 1 é igual ao elemento da posição `i + 1`, que por sua vez é igual ao elemento da posição `i + 2` subtraído de 1. Se for, eu imprimo os números e interrompo o *loop* com `break`.

Se não tiver 3 números consecutivos, ele não chega no `break` e cai no `else` (sim, o `else` é do `for`, [em Python isso é perfeitamente possível](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9979970)).

---

Não sei porque você criou a lista `C`, pois se a ideia é só saber se tem ou não, nem precisaria guardar os números. Mas se quiser, pode fazer um *slice* para obter a lista de consecutivos:

```
numeros = [10, 5, 7, 9, 20, 16, 11, 12, 13, 3]
for i in range(len(numeros) - 2):
    consecutivos = numeros[i:i + 3] # slice para pegar os elementos i, i + 1 e i + 2
    if consecutivos[0] + 1 == consecutivos[1] == consecutivos[2] - 1:
        break
else: # se não achou, deixa a lista de consecutivos vazia
    consecutivos = []

if consecutivos: # se a lista não está vazia
    print(f'Os números consecutivos são {", ".join(map(str, consecutivos))}')
else: # se a lista é vazia
    print('não tem 3 números consecutivos')
```

---

E tem também a solução - meio *over enginnered* e baseada [nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5434936) - usando o [módulo `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import tee

def threes(iterator):
    a, b, c = tee(iterator, 3)
    next(b, None)
    next(c, None)
    next(c, None)
    return zip(a, b, c)

numeros = [10, 5, 7, 9, 20, 16, 11, 12, 13, 3]
for a, b, c in threes(numeros):
    if a + 1 == b == c - 1:
        consecutivos = [a, b, c]
        break
else:
    consecutivos = []

if consecutivos: # se a lista não está vazia
    print(f'Os números consecutivos são {", ".join(map(str, consecutivos))}')
else: # se a lista é vazia
    print('não tem 3 números consecutivos')
```

A ideia é que [`tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) gera 3 iteradores independentes a partir da lista de números. Como todos apontam para o início da lista, eu chamo `next` para que `b` aponte para o segundo elemento e `c` aponte para o terceiro. Depois uso [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) que retorna um iterador para os 3 iteradores gerados (`a` aponta para o primeiro elemento, `b` para o segundo, e `c` para o terceiro).

Ao iterar pelo resultado de tudo isso, eu tenho sempre 3 números consecutivos da lista, e aí basta fazer a mesma verificação dos exemplos anteriores. Como `zip` se encerra quando o menor dos iteradores terminar, o *loop* termina corretamente quando chego ao último número.

Answer (score 1):

Uma abordagem numérica em duas linhas. `Passo 1` localiza quais valores tem uma taxa de variação igual a `1`. `Passo 2` testa se há sequência de valor `True`.

```py
import numpy as np 
A = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10,)) 
print(A) 

out = (A[1:] - A[:-1]) == 1    # passo 1
out = out[1:] & out[:-1]       # passo 2

print(f"Tem 3 números consecutivos: {True in out}")
```

**Extra**: Para sequências repetidas substitua, no `Passo 1`, o valor `1` por `0` e para sequências decrescentes, substitua o `1` por `-1`. A proposta segue a mesma ideia de numa derivada discreta.

Answer (score 1):

Se o objetivo é identificar todas sequências de três números inteiros consecutivos em uma lista, uma opção é a [comparação de sequencias](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types) :

```
n = [-3, -2, -1, 10, 5, 7, 9, 20, 16, 11, 12, 13, 3]
result = []                                 #Inicializa a variável que receberá o resultado.
#Para todos elemento i,v na enumeração do primeiro ao antepenúltimo elemento n...
for i, v in enumerate(n[:-2]):  
  #...verifica se a fatia [n[i],n[i+1],n[i2]] for igual a lista de consecutivos [v,v+1,v+2]...
  if (c:=n[i:i+3]) == [*range(v, v+3)]:     
    result.append(c)                        #...se sim apensa a fatia ao resultado.

print(*result, sep="\n")                    #imprime o resultado
```

O algoritmo cria uma [enumeração](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) do primeiro ao antepenúltimo elemento da lista `n` e itera, com `i` o índice e `v` valor , por essa enumeração comparando o [slice](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html) formado pelos três elementos adjacentes a `n[i]` com a lista formada pelos três números consecutivos a partir de `v`.
Se a comparação constatar equivalência a sequencia é apensada a `result`, se não ouver equivalência passa a próxima comparação.

O mesmo código acima usando [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
n = [-3, -2, -1, 10, 5, 7, 9, 20, 16, 11, 12, 13, 3]
l = [c for i, v in enumerate(n[:-2]) if (c:=n[i:i+3]) == [*range(v, v+3)]]
print(*l, sep="\n")
```

Ambos os códigos acima resultam:

```
[-3, -2, -1]
[11, 12, 13]
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do loop eu faria algo assim:

```
if i+2 < len(A) -1:
   if A[i] == A[i+1] -1 and A[i] == A[i+2] - 2:
       contem_consecutivos = True
```

Primeiro vejo se tem 2 números a frente, se tiver, ele vê se o próximo numero menos 1 é igual ao numero atual e se o depois do próximo menos 2 também for, eles são consecutivos